# How to config nginx to include headers into response?

Tags: nginx, cors

I have nginx which proxies requests to app server `browser <=> nginx <=> app_server`.

For some reason not all headers provided by `app_server` will be returned to the browser.

I.e. headers like `Access-Control-Allow-***` will removed from the response.

How to fix this?

My current location config is:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://app_server:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Origin '';
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_buffering off;
}
```

Comment: This requires the complete nginx configuration. Please  run `nginx -T` and post the complete output.

Comment: Nginx doesn't remove any headers from the upstream reply unless you tamper with them in the configuration.

Comment: @drookie, thank you! Your comment helped me to look into the right direction. I actually made mistake, by erasing `Origin` header, that's why app_server didn't respond to CORS pre-flight request and then didn't include it in actual request. If you want, put it as a suggested answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the cause of this behavior. By adding

`proxy_set_header Origin '';`

I've basically removed this header from proxied request to app_server. Hence, app_server didn't return any CORS headers. As soon as I changed it to

`proxy_set_header Origin '$http_origin';`

everything worked properly.